# create function hollow square in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to create hollow square with function in javascript.

this my code

```js
let test = num => {
  var edge = '*';
  var inside = ' ';
  var printline;

  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i === 1 || i === num) {
      printline = Array(num + 1).join(edge);
    } else {
      printline = edge + Array(num - 1).join(inside) + edge;
    }
  }
  return printline;
}
console.log(test(4));
```

currently output is
`****`

but i want my output like this

```
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please update the lines of codes below.

```
 var printline = '';

printline += Array(num + 1).join(edge) + '\n';
printline += edge + Array(num - 1).join(inside) + edge + '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should reuse printline, not overwrite it.
Also, it needs the new line and carriage return (\r\n) on every iteration

```js
let test = num => {
  var edge = '*';
  var inside = ' ';
  var printline='';

  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i === 1 || i === num) {
      printline += Array(num + 1).join(edge);
    } else {
      printline += edge + Array(num - 1).join(inside) + edge;
    }
    printline+='\r\n';
  }
  return printline;
}
console.log(test(4));
```